# Issues With Cura 4.6.1 Effecting Text Width On The Initial Layer

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

I'm have an issue where Cura 4.6.1 is effecting the width of certain characters if the part is orented to print them on the the bottom. The initial layer seems to be the only layer that is effected. It is also only effects certain characters, in this case characters 4,6,8 and 9. Picture 1 shows the part oriented to print text on the bottom. Picture 2 shows the same part oriented where the text is on the top, which results in the text looking correct.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I have looked for the setting that causes this but, so far, have been unable to locate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Brim setting was causing the issue.

Comment: Doesn't Cura have a setting to prevent generation of brim in "holes"?

Comment: Yep. It's called "Brim Only On Outside" (`brim_outside_only`).